# Problem with access to chat room(s)/parent user

Tags: support, chat

Clicking on the chatroom button next to the current community in the top SE top drop-down menu
  [image: drop-down menu]
used to lead me directly to the entrance to the chatroom of this current community.

Now whatever current community I'm in, clicking on the chat button leads me to the general StackExchange chat showing no entrances to chatrooms
[image: general StackExchange chat]

and to access the chatrooms I have to click on my user name at the top horizontal menu bar to see invite to entrances to the chatrooms. Moreover I am invited only to access the chatrooms I have only recently visited and can't any longer access chatrooms I could previously access. 
[image: access to chatrooms]

Problem remains the same when I try changing parent user access.
[image: changing parent user]

When I leave the chatroom I'm taken back to the StackExchange chat general portal instead of the portal of the parent user as it used to be the case before the problem appeared.

I asked the question on FL - my main community - but so far only one other user said they'd encountered the same problem.

Bug or new feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point, you clicked the tab labeled "mine":

> [image]

This tab is showing you only the rooms you're currently in.

The problem is, that tabs in Stack Exchange are "sticky". The last tab you chose is being remembered forever, until you click other tab. That's the case with many tabs, e.g. question lists, profile page etc.

So just click the "site" tab and you'll see only the site chat rooms again.

Also, parent user is totally not relevant here. The site is decided based on the [HTTP referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), i.e. from which site you clicked the "chat" link.

Comment: What is wrong with the image here?

Comment: @rene the only problem I see is that it only contains one FHRC.

Comment: @rene yeah, saw it now. Solved by browsing directly to the image, guess clearing the cache will also work.