# Chat link in dropdown goes to all rooms instead of site rooms

Tags: discussion, chat, top-bar

The StackExchange drop down menu from the main or meta pages of a site contains a link to chat in the Current Community section. Instead of linking to the list of site rooms, this links to all rooms.

I believe this had previously linked to just site rooms, which the link shown below seems to confirm. I expect this would be much easier for relatively new users wanting to chat about the specific community they are reaching chat from.

Is this affecting all communities? I have confirmed that both Computer Graphics and Programming Puzzles & Code Golf have chat links to all rooms instead of site rooms.

## Example link

From Computer Graphics, the chat link is this:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=computergraphics.stackexchange.com

This certainly looks like it is intended to show site rooms, but the page that is displayed lists rooms from many sites, and says "a list of all rooms" at the top, with the tab title being "all rooms | chat.stackexchange.com"

Comment: Can't reproduce. Right click the chat link, choose "copy link address" and paste it here please.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for pointing this out - I've edited in a link

Comment: [status-norepro]. The page I get from clicking your link shows only CG rooms.

Answer (score 2):

I got an [answer in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30628598#30628598):

> This has always been like this. The host parameter prioritizes the site-specific rooms in the list (i.e. they'll appear *first*).

This seems the ideal behaviour, providing instant access to all the rooms of the current site, plus a list of all rooms on other sites after these.

I've changed the question from [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) to [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) as this is intended behaviour, and I'll leave the question here for anyone raising this in future to find.

---

## Two different behaviours

I was sure I'd seen just site rooms in the past, but another user confirmed that the page has always shown all rooms, with site rooms prioritised. It turns out we were both right, as it depends on an individual user's previous choices.

It is possible to override which tab is displayed when linking to the room list. For example, [all rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&host=computergraphics.stackexchange.com) and [site rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=computergraphics.stackexchange.com) both link to the chat room page, but override the user's previous choices to select the "all" and "site" tabs on that page, respectively.

The link from the drop down menu does not override the tab, so the page displays whichever tab the user previously selected (or the "site" tab for users who have never changed this). This is what allows two different users to follow the same link and see different tabs.

Now that I understand it, I don't see this as a problem. New users will just see site rooms, and users who have changed the tab will still see site rooms prioritised, so no one should have any difficulty finding what they are looking for.

Comment: Don't forget you can accept this (self-)answer

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to what I explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280481/152859). At some point, you clicked the "all" tab, or visited a link with the `tab=all` in the querystring. And this cause this tab to stick.

In my opinion this is bad, and if there is a "host" querystring parameter, it should override and always show the  "site" tab.