# Intermittent Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request

Tags: support, imgur, uploader

Just now when trying to upload an image with the image uploader I'm greeted intermittently with the following error:

> Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request

That error comes from the POST on `https://meta.stackexchange.com/upload/image?https=true`

I initially was on an non-encrypted HTTP connection. Switching to HTTPS seemed to resolve the issue.

In this same time-frame I also [notice that images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280480/problem-with-access-to-chat-rooms-parent-user/280481#comment946850_280481) that are hosted on i.stack.imgur.com are not served or only after refreshing a couple of times.

I have verified in chat that it is [not only me](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5806517#5806517) and I rule out caching.

Can this be looked at and if possible fixed?

Comment: I assume imgur DNS has issues, I think that's how Gravatar started to fall apart. Really hope they won't ignore it like Gravatar do.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mah7s.png Just took 4 reloads to access.

Comment: Now I get “Imgur is over capacity”.

Comment: +1 I've had the same issue for the last 24 hours.

Comment: Same problem here....

Comment: The image wasn't showing up when I tried to upload stuff, but it uploaded - if I went to the URL it gave me, I could see it.

Comment: Same is happening for me when I try to upload a 1.7Mb gif on bio.SE

Comment: I'm having the same problem

Comment: It happens even with very small (~ 10 KB) images

Comment: If the servers at [Amazon S3](http://status.aws.amazon.com/) don't accept the network-packets the size doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It appears that S3 has fallen over in AWS for the US-EAST1. Ironically I can't include a screenshot of the dashboard in this post, but I promise I have one.

You can see the AWS status dashboard here: https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Imgur uploads should return successfully once that issue has settled. Apologies for the trouble, but we're not in a position to do much about it for the moment. We're working on some long-term backup bits but they're far from being in place.

We're also [fighting a botnet](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/836404479054524419) (no idea if this is related, it's unlikely), so busy on a few fronts at the moment.

Comment: Maybe the webcam botnet also DDoSing imgur by uploading millions of images per second?

Comment: _"fighting a botnet"_ ... I just imagined all the Team avatars in knight's armor awaiting an oncoming horde of robotic insects. (I'm thinking giant ants because they are a pain to get rid of.) This image is so much more epic than the reality of fighting a botnet, so I will continue to assume it is done this way to make you all more epic.

Comment: Shucks, hang in there fellas. Rooting for you.

Comment: @Kendra Funny, Stargate's Replicators came to mind when I read that.

Comment: accepting this answer now, as the S3 issues have been resolved. Thanks Nick for your hard work and dedication.

Comment: Though the issue has been resolved, I might add [the official imgur's tweet](https://twitter.com/imgur/status/836645670954008576) regarding this issue, and [its support page](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001058186) for reference.

Comment: @qwer it's not resolved, I still get broken images ~80% of the times and have to reload a lot to see images.

Comment: @Kendra "To dream... the impossible dream..."

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, something's still jacked up. I'll ping folks internally (or hey, here. HI NICK) to see if we can reach out to our contacts at Imgur and figure out what's what.