# Since Imgur is down, is there an alternative?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur

Imgur uploading is currently off-line: [Intermittent Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291609/158428)

Many answers are rather dependent on being able to include images; is there an alternative host to use while this problem persists?

I know that Imgur is out of the control of Stack Exchange; this question is not a duplicate of the one linked. I am not asking for Stack Exchange to look into or try to fix the problem.

Incidentally https://imgbb.com also appears to be down at the moment. That is the #2 result on a Google search for "image host."

It seems that postimg.org is working for the time being:

[image: postimg.org test #1]

Comment: @JakeGould I just linked to that question in my opening sentence!  This is not a duplicate.  I am asking what to do *because of* that problem.

Comment: You can try ImageShack.us ... oh no wait: those [delete images](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene?tab=activity&sort=revisions) at will. Maybe just wait it out until Amazon solved their S3 issue that impacts imgur?

Comment: A stop-gap that works till the other service goes down. And then we have to migrate all those images back to imgur.

Comment: @Oded Isn't that a small price to pay for continued function of the site,  rather that ceasing posting until this issue is resolved?

Comment: One can keep posting. But complicating everything for the future trying to produce a stop gap for a temporary outage is not constructive.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard if the outage will last for weeks then you're right, better find alternative and maybe stick with it, hoping it will be better than imgur. But otherwise, I tend to agree with Oded and rene, better wait it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can include images from any other image host or personal webspace, in theory. But there are significant drawbacks to many alternative image hosting solutions. Many free ones expire, and any image hosts that don't serve via SSL will break once SE uses encryption by default.

So I'd just wait out the outage and continue using imgur, instead of using external image hosting.

Comment: Regarding SSL: We already stopped allowing embedded images from displaying at all if they aren't accessible via a secure connection [on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images). That change will eventually go out over the entire network too.

Comment: @animuson I'd go even further and disallow any image hosts not controlled by SE. It's just seriously annoying if you don't have control over the images, this inevitably breaks at some point in the future

Comment: Until this event for some reason I thought that image links to other servers were automatically re-uploaded to imgur and relinked.  I don't know why.  Has that *ever* been done?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard nope, and I doubt there's even such a feature request. I think what confuse you is the option to upload image via URL in the upload dialog of SE, which is doing what you said, but it's not automatic.