# Images from stack.imgur.com are not displaying

Tags: bug, images, imgur

Few images from [`https://i.stack.imgur.com`](https://i.stack.imgur.com) are not displaying.

For an example: [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343134/2451726) contains two images from `stack.imgur`. One image is displaying properly the other one is not displaying. This issue is not only on Meta SO, it is on [Meta ELU](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7632/154058) and on other sites too.

When opening the image it shows the warning as:

> The image “https://i.stack.imgur.com/abcde.png” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Image not displaying issue]

Comment: They serve a 503 *again* ... not sure what is up with imgur lately.

Comment: seems to be similar like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291609/intermittent-failed-to-upload-image-imgur-is-rejecting-the-request) then ... but with a different root-cause I guess.

Comment: I'm afraid imgur is going in the same path as Gravatar... they became too big to care. Only option for Stack Exchange is host the images themselves, as no image host can be trusted any more.

Comment: I'm seeing this too; rather frequently (at least a couple of times a week).

Comment: The post you referenced is doing fine for me just now. A moment ago I saw similar errors for http://i.stack.imgur.com/dLpew.png from [a Math answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/730003/35416) with “503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity” as the error message. Now it's back again. So it's apparently a transient thing, but still bad for experience.

Comment: Same today, I got 503 at https://i.stack.imgur.com/.